# Python Dataclass: Attribute type in scope but not recognized by interpreter

Tags: python-dataclasses

The following code

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum


@dataclass
class Foo:
    type: FooType


class FooType(Enum):
    BAR = 0,
    BAZ = 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo(type=FooType.BAR)
```

gives the following error

```
❯ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Foo:
  File "test.py", line 7, in Foo
    type: FooType
          ^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'FooType' is not defined
```

when I believe it should not. FooType is in the same file, which I believe means it should be in scope when inside of Foo.

I appreciate any insight on this as I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

It appaears that your definiton for `FooType` appears after the definition of `Foo` class type so the runtime process will not see the type definition in time to use it for your runtime class definition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although it contains poor spelling and grammar.